# Allowing a port through my firewall doesn't work

Tags: windows-8, firewall, port-forwarding

I've been trying to forward port 1604. When I disable my firewall canyouseeme.org says the port is open. When I turn it back on, it says it doesn't work.

I have port 1604 allowed in my my firewall inbound and outbound. Every single setting is set to "Any" in the advanced part of firewall. What am I doing wrong?

I'm using windows firewall.

Comment: Please include the settings used on all pages of the Firewall rule.  As there are more settings than just allowing "Any" that could stop this fro working.

Comment: http://imgur.com/2vnn6VC,PpiIHSC

Comment: You need to include all firewall rules. there is undoubtedly another one, more general, that is set to explicitly block ports that include 1604.

Comment: I found a rule called "MITCHRIBARYTUBE" that blocked every port. I disabled it and 1604 works now. If you want to make your comment an answer I'll vote it up and check it.

Comment: @Nik - See comments above, you got the correct answer! chipperyman573, you need to include the @ and the persons name, otherwise they won't know you've sent them a message :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include all firewall rules. there is undoubtedly another one, more general, that is set to explicitly block ports that include 1604.

Comment: That was so true! I just sorted 'Inbound rules' by 'Action' column so that block rules appear on top and then I saw the more general rule that was overriding my allow rule.